# How to reshape these images to fit this k-means code?

Tags: python, arrays, image, k-means

I have 25 images saved into a folder called 'SV_cluster.' If I click on the properties of the image, it says: 432x288 pixels, 72 dpi, 24 bit depth. I'm trying to pass those images through this k-means clustering code, but I get this error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (0,newaxis)

The images were generated from an array produced by a CGAN code. This array is called "imgarray". I was thinking maybe I can just pass the array through kmeans to just skip the process of having to save them in a folder and then call them from the folder. This array has a shape of (25, 64, 128, 1).

When I try to do this by setting image=imgarray & skipping the resizing/reshaping part, I get this error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 204800 into shape (224,224,3)

So that doesn't work either.

This is the k-means code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import save
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
import cv2
import os, glob, shutil


input_dir = 'Documents/UCSDproject/SV_cluster/'
glob_dir = input_dir + '/*.jpg'
images = [cv2.resize(cv2.imread(file), (224, 224)) for file in glob.glob(glob_dir)]
#print(images)
paths = [file for file in glob.glob(glob_dir)]
images = np.array(np.float32(images).reshape(len(images), -1)/255)

images=gen_imgs
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False,weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
predictions = model.predict(images.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3))
pred_images = predictions.reshape(images.shape[0], -1)

k = 4
kmodel = KMeans(n_clusters = k, n_jobs=-1, random_state=728)
kmodel.fit(pred_images)
kpredictions = kmodel.predict(pred_images)
shutil.rmtree(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\FALL 2020\Research\kmeans\output")


for i in range(k):
    os.makedirs(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\FALL 2020\Research\kmeans\output\cluster" + str(i))
for i in range(len(paths)):
    shutil.copy2(paths[i], r"C:\Users\User\Documents\FALL 2020\Research\kmeans\output\cluster" + str(kpredictions[i]))
```